# How to always boot in recovery mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, xiaomi, magisk

I'm using Magisk and, because my device (lavender with Android 11) does not have ramdisk in the boot images, I have to boot in recovery mode (not to recovery, only in recovery mode) every time I want to have root enabled.

So my question is, is there a tweak to automatically boot in recovery mode every time ? Maybe a script or something (I am not very familiar with these) ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: i think you have rooted wrong. you can use magisk in boot

Comment: No, It's pretty common : https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#magisk-in-recovery

Comment: this section is for samsung, and there is special note that instructions not valid for xiaomi. root magisk in boot